# How to get a static IP?

Tags: proxy, port-forwarding, static-ip, squid, noip

I need a static IP to work on one of my client's website. He have blocked all connections from my country in firewal. And asked me my IP address so he could whitelist mine. Problem is I don't have a static IP.

I read that this can be done using noip.com. I followed the tutorial but it did't worked. I setuped port forwarding on my router but when I check on canyouseeme.org it says the ports are closed. I've followed roughly 5 tutorials online for the last 3 hours but with no luck.

I also tried using my windows vps as proxy server, I setuped squid proxy, opened ports and the port shows open when I check online. But when I try to connect to the proxy from firefox, it doesn't work. I'm really frustrated.

Comment: noip.com will not get you a static ip. It will get you a static hostname that translates to an ip. You have to check with your client if they can use hostnames, otherwise its pointless. That said, getting a static ip is only something your ISP can give you. Often they require a business account. Alternatively, you could figure out how often your IP changes. Even though you may have a dynamic IP address, if the address doesn't change that often, consider working on your clients website as fast as possible, so he only has to whitelist it once. (like off-site developing, ftping the result)

Comment: Ok, I'm using a workaround. I'm using a proxy to access the clent's website. Simple, easy and cheap. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score -2):

Use a DDNS service. Lots of free ones out there as well. Here is an article:
https://smartdns.com/blog/60/5-best-free-ddns-providers/

Comment: -1 from me because the first in that list is noip.com, where the poster already made a mention of trying to do this but not getting it to work. Next to that, a DDNS service does not give you a static IP address. It gives you a hostname that refers to an IP Address. If the firewall does not support hostnames, this solution is not even going to work. Although technically it could still be an answer, the fact that OP already mentioned it makes this a -1 for me.